# A finiteness condition for Grothendieck categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a locally finitely generated Grothendieck category. Let us say that an object $X$ of $\mathcal{E}$ is *finitely cogenerated* if every set of subojects of $X$ whose intersection is zero has a finite subset whose intersection is zero (this finiteness property is standard, but I do not know whether its name is fixed).

Let us consider the following condition on $\mathcal{E}$:

(C) **Every object of $\mathcal{E}$ which is both finitely generated and finitely cogenerated is finite (that is, of finite length).**

(It is trivially equivalent to the fact that the injective hulls of simple objects of $\mathcal{E}$ are locally finite.)

Has this property been yet studied? Are there nice equivalent characterisations of (C) under suitable further assumptions on $\mathcal{E}$? I am indeed interested with locally finitely *presented* Grothendieck categories and espacially categories of abelian presheaves on a small additive category. Even if $\mathcal{E}$ is the category of left $R$-modules, I know very few things about (C), except obvious situations (for example, $R$ left artinian, of $R$ commutative and noetherian, implies (C)).

Comment: A step might be to use Oberst's results in his paper: Duality theory for Grothendieck categories and linearly compact rings, Journal of Algebra
Volume 15, Issue 4, August 1970, Pages 473-542. The condition you call finitely cogenerated would seem to be related to linear compactness and Oberst's characterisation of the duals of Grothendick categories may help.